# React, donde debería hacer la peticion de eliminacion?

Tags: reactjs

Quiero eliminar un elemento elemento de una lista y tengo la siguiente jerarquia de componentes:

index.jsx > App.jsx > router/Router.jsx > Pages/Index.jsx > Card.jsx

pages/index

```
export default function Index() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(URL_API_BASE + 'products?page=1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setProducts(data['hydra:member']));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container my-5">
            <h1>Listado de productos</h1>
            <Card products={products} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Card

```
export default function Card({ products }) {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="row">
      {products.map(theProduct => {
        return (
          <div key={theProduct.name} className="card mt-5 p-3 col-4">
            <img src="" className="card-img-top" />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{theProduct.name}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">Description statica</p>
              <a href={URL_APP_BASE + 'edit/' + theProduct.id} className="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
              <a className="btn btn-danger deleted" >Borrar</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Mi duda:
1)donde corresponde hacer la peticion del delete y su posterior actualizacion en el DOM?
2)Como la podría hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera en la que yo intentaría hacer lo que estás preguntando sería así:

Primero, en **pages/index** me aseguraría de pasarle al componente Card no solo el estado `products` si no también su respectiva función para setearlo: `setProducts`.

De esta manera:

```
 <Card products={products} setProducts={setProducts}  />
```

Luego, dentro del componente **Card** hay que recibir ahora las 2 props:

```
export default function Card({ products, setProducts  }) {  ...
```

Haciendo eso, no sería necesario volver a crearlos con `useState([])` otra vez dentro del componente Card.

Ahora el próximo paso sería hacer una función que actualice el array que está dentro de `products` eliminando el indice del array correspondiente y poder llamar esa función desde el `<a>`.

La función para eliminar podría ser algo como esto:

```
const deleteOfArray = (param) => {

  var index = products.indexOf( param );

  products.splice( index, 1 );
  
  setProducts(products)

}
```

Dentro de `param` estaría el producto que necesitas eliminar, luego en `index` guardamos su indice, osea la ubicación, en donde ese producto está guardado dentro del array. Después mediante el `.splice` quitamos todo el elemento del array pesándole su respectivo indice.

Y por último, al usar la función `setProducts()` vas a actualizar el estado del componente **pages/index** el cual al detectar cambios en su estado se re-renderizará actualizando así el nuevo listado de productos en el DOM.

Pero no hay que olvidarse de que el `<a>` para Borrar debería llamar a esa función en un evento `onClick` así:

```
<a className="btn btn-danger deleted" onClick ={() => deleteOfArray(theProduct)} >Borrar</a>
```

Como argumento le pasamos el `theProduct` que se usará luego como parámetro en la función `deleteOfArray` y le dará un valor a `param`.

Comment: Por mas que le pase el setProducts no se actualiza el estado del componente padre..

Comment: ¿Eliminaste ya el `useState([])` del componente Card? Porque si no lo hiciste es posible que en Card estés seteando el estado local y no el del padre, ya que ambos tienen los mismos nombres.